# how to dynamically add a value to a drop down in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

if I have a drop down on a page that lists some values which are in a DB table.

next to the drop down I have something which when clicked makes a text box. Kind of like Edit in place. is it possible to type some value there hit enter and have that value be loaded up in the drop down?

Answer (score 1):

If the select box is is a list of dongles, and `Dongle` is a resource:

In your `SomethingElseController`:

```
@new_dongle = Dongle.new
```

In your view:

```
<% remote_form_for @new_dongle do |dongle_form| %>
   <%= dongle_form.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Check out the [api docs for remote_form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001649). If you want the id of the just created object, look at the callback parameters for `link_to_remote` on the same page.